# Truffle migrate not working

Tags: go-ethereum, truffle, blockchain, ethereum-wallet-dapp, truffle-migration

Every time I enter `truffle migrate` command in the terminal it doesn't do anything but takes some time and nothing happens after that. I am using Truffle version 5.0.4

Answer (score 1):

You need to give more information...
I assume this is similar to what has happened to me. If you are using Linux or Mac probably it wasn't compiled. When it does not do anything it is because it had nothing to migrate. Try:
1) check if your migration files are correct
2) compile with sudo "sudo truffle compile"